# grails and spring security core plugin - authenticateion from client

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

i am starting to use spring-security-core-1.1.3 plugin with grails.
My application for authentication sends request to server:

```
def authSomeAction = {
    def req = ...//http requet here
    if(req.contains("yes")){
       render "There is such user"
    }else{
       render "There is no such user"
    }
}
```

I can successfully authenticate using SpringSecurityUtils.reauthenticate(username, password) method only if i have created users in client side

Can anybody please in details help me to understand how i have to implement
plugin work in client side(without database)...?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to Grails, so I could clearly be way off base, but I suspect that your issue may have to do with the way that you are encoding the password upon user creation.  Are you doing it the same when you create users using the "client side" vs. what other method you are using?

For example, when I first started using the spring-security-ui plugin, I created users with the utility that is bundled and they all failed to log in.  If I understand properly, the spring-security-core was updated since spring-security-ui, which has shifted the need to encode the password in the controllers to within the User itself.  For example, in the spring-security-ui UserController.save() that comes with that plugin, this occurs:

```
if (params.password) {
    String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : params.username
    user.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(params.password, salt)
}
```

But my User class then has this (straight from the s2 plugin examples)

```
def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}
```

Since my User class manages encoding itself, there was a double-encoding going which was causing the logins to fail that were created with it. Could there be something similar to this going on in your application?  When you are creating users other than from the client side, are you encoding the same way?

Comment: Dave Shuck thanks for reply...yes i encode password in "client side'
i have no problem with encoding password, i only thinking  about how to organize plugin work in client side..